# MongoDB "$" projection with "OR" condition

Tags: mongodb, nosql, projection

Our team has a trouble with MongoDB projection queries.

We have two field which is team1 and team2 and players are inside this teams. For example, we have a player that name is yvalentine.

Yvalentine is play its first game in team1. But second time, he can play in team2. We need to get yvalentine's statistics in both of these teams (Valentine can only be on one team at same time).

First game score :
[This time, yvalentine is in team1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AMof8.png)
Second game score:
[This time, yvalentine is in team2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MMMI8.png)

So we try this command:

```
db.game_statistics.find({$or:[{'team1.user_name': "yvalentine"},{'team2.user_name': "yvalentine"}]},{$or:[{"team1.kill.$":1},{"team2.kill.$":1}]})
```

But it is not working. How we can solve this projection problem? Thx for your help!

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Can you post the sample document as **snippet** but **not images** so it will be easier for us to debugging. Thanks.

Comment: There is no `$or` projection operator, what are you expecting that to do?